# Binary(16) truncate to binary(4) in CASE statement

Tags: sql, sql-server

Have a table:

```
CREATE TABLE [db].[Table1](
    [Id] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Hash] [binary](16) NOT NULL
)
```

With data:

```
Id Hash
1  0x00000000000000000000000000000000
2  0x00000000000000000000000000000000
```

And trying to execute SQL:

```
UPDATE Table1 SET Hash = CASE Id
WHEN 1 THEN 0x4cb47abddf8a9c348c7a7c20abd0b1d5
ELSE 0
END
```

Expect that value in column Hash is 0x4cb47abddf8a9c348c7a7c20abd0b1d5 but actual is 0x00000000000000000000000abd0b1d5.

If I try:

```
UPDATE Table1 SET Hash =  0x4cb47abddf8a9c348c7a7c20abd0b1d5
```

Everything is ok.

Comment: Try specifying a binary literal in the CASE expression ELSE value: `0x00000000000000000000000000000000`.

Comment: `CASE` has to return a *single* type. Each `WHEN` branch in this statement though returns a different type. `int` has a higher precedence than `binary` so the compiler decides to return `int` instead of `binary(16)`

Comment: `0x0` should suffice, actually. Anything that has type `BINARY`. But not `0`, since that has type `INT`, and T-SQL's arcane conversion rules *force* data loss by converting the larger value to an `INT`.

Comment: The data type precedence is [described in the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/data-type-precedence-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) and `binary` has the lowest precedence of all

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Binary has the lowest precedence of any datatype in SQL Server ([Data Type Precendence (SQL Server)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/data-type-precedence-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)):

> SQL Server uses the following precedence order for data types:
>
> 1. user-defined data types (highest)
> 2. sql_variant
> 3. xml
> 4. datetimeoffset
> 5. datetime2
> 6. datetime
> 7. smalldatetime
> 8. date
> 9. time
> 10. float
> 11. real
> 12. decimal
> 13. money
> 14. smallmoney
> 15. bigint
> 16. int
> 17. smallint
> 18. tinyint
> 19. bit
> 20. ntext
> 21. text
> 22. image
> 23. timestamp
> 24. uniqueidentifier
> 25. nvarchar (including nvarchar(max) )
> 26. nchar
> 27. varchar (including varchar(max) )
> 28. char
> 29. varbinary (including varbinary(max) )
> 30. binary (lowest)

With a `CASE` expression, all return values are implicitly converted to the datatype with the highest value in the return values. In this case you have the `int` value `0`, and the `binary(16)` value `0x4cb47abddf8a9c348c7a7c20abd0b1d5`. As `int` > `binary`, the value `0x4cb47abddf8a9c348c7a7c20abd0b1d5` is converted to an `int`, and thus you loss data.

If the return types of your data is important, and you are using multiple data types in your return values, explicitly convert all the values to the correct type. In this case:

```
UPDATE Table1
SET Hash = CASE Id WHEN 1 THEN 0x4cb47abddf8a9c348c7a7c20abd0b1d5
                   ELSE CONVERT(binary(16),0)
                   END;
```